# access value attribute data

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have the below form suppose I choose the first option. I want to ask is There a way to access `value =0` and converted to number rather than A if the form submitedd

```
    <form  id="rpoerForm" action="http://localhost:5000/result" class="form"  method="post" >
        <div class="form__input-group">
           <label for="City">Select city</label>
   <select name="City" id="City" class="Input">
            <option value='0'>A</option>
            <option value='1'>B</option>
            <option value='2'>C</option>
            <option value='3'>D</option>
            <option value='4'>E</option>
            <option value='5'>F</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: Im not quite sure, but your form is doing fine, unless the code is not complete like, you are missing endtag `</div></form>`

Comment: Yes. You can access the value of of select field ```document.getElementById('City').value```

Comment: `document.getElementById('City').value` that will give me A B C or 0 1 2 ?

Comment: You do not need to change anything.  Submit will send the option value and not option text,

Comment: @Yogi I use flask but when I try submit error say `cant convert string to float 'City'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, `onsubmit` you will receive an array with the values of all inputs/select inside the form inside a tuple with the shape ["name", value] :

```js
rpoerForm.onsubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const data = [...new FormData(e.target).entries()].map(entry => [entry[0], +entry[1]])
  console.log(data)
}
```

```html
<form id="rpoerForm" action="http://localhost:5000/result" class="form" method="post">
  <div class="form__input-group">
    <label for="City">Select city</label>
    <select name="City" id="City" class="Input">
      <option value='0'>A</option>
      <option value='1'>B</option>
      <option value='2'>C</option>
      <option value='3'>D</option>
      <option value='4'>E</option>
      <option value='5'>F</option>
    </select>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes usually you use ajax calls when you do send data to the server not directly a `form action`, you can send a `JSON` object or even simply convert the form data to search params with `new URLSearchParams(data)` and pass that for example as params to a GET query.

Answer (score 1):

simply you can do it in jquery

```
<form id="rpoerForm">
  <div class="form__input-group">
    <label for="City">Select city</label>
    <select name="City" id="City" class="Input">
      <option value='0'>A</option>
      <option value='1'>B</option>
      <option value='2'>C</option>
      <option value='3'>D</option>
      <option value='4'>E</option>
      <option value='5'>F</option>
    </select>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```js
$('#submit').on("click",function(){
  console.log($('#City option').val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="rpoerForm">
  <div class="form__input-group">
    <label for="City">Select city</label>
    <select name="City" id="City" class="Input">
      <option value='0'>A</option>
      <option value='1'>B</option>
      <option value='2'>C</option>
      <option value='3'>D</option>
      <option value='4'>E</option>
      <option value='5'>F</option>
    </select>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```